# How can I label rows of one dataframe according to a range specified in 2 columnns (start and end) of another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, sequence

Apologies if this has been asked before - I tried to search but I might not know the right terms to search for. 
I have data in the following format:

in one data frame (utterances) I have the start and end frames of utterances in my data set

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2)
utterance_number <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,4)
start_frame <- c(20,35,67,10,44,56,72)
end_frame <- c(29,44,72,15,52,69,82)

utterances <- cbind(id, utterance_number, start_frame, end_frame)
utterances
```

in another data frame I have all of the frames

```
id <- c(rep(1,80), rep(2,90))
frame <- c(seq(1:80), seq(1:90))
val1 <- sample(170)
val2 <- sample(170)

values <- cbind(id, frame, val1, val2)
values
```

I want to label each frame in values with its utterance_number, or with NA if it is not part of an utterance. So in a new column "Utterance_number" in values, the first 19 frames would be NA, frames 20-29 would be labelled "1" and so on.

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Need some more detail here. What is `val1` and `val2` and how is it related to your question?

Comment: they are just values that variables in my real data take. In my real data I have 25 + columns of variables taking different values at each frame (XYZ values for different joints in the body), I've just represented them here as val1 and val2 with random values so that I would be able to hopefully see how to incorporate the value-containing columns into the solution that I end up applying to my real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` and expand `utterances` using `apply`.

```
merge(values, do.call(rbind, apply(utterances, 1
  , function(x) cbind(id=x[1], frame=x[3]:x[4], utterance_number=x[2])))
 , all.x=TRUE)
#    id frame val1 val2 utterance_number
#1    1     1  166  138               NA
#2    1     2   54  109               NA
#3    1     3   71  103               NA
#4    1     4    9   48               NA
#...
#17   1    17   32   22               NA
#18   1    18  170  100               NA
#19   1    19   57  112               NA
#20   1    20   45  110                1
#21   1    21   25  148                1
#22   1    22   13   25                1
#...
#28   1    28   56   62                1
#29   1    29  130   47                1
#30   1    30  163   15               NA
#31   1    31  110   64               NA
#...
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you unpack this a little to help me understand what the different parts are doing?

Comment: `tt <- apply(utterances, 1, function(x) cbind(id=x[1], frame=x[3]:x[4], utterance_number=x[2]))`

Comment: `tt <- do.call(rbind, tt)`

Comment: `merge(values, tt, all.x=TRUE)`